# What is the first synchronization scope of vkCmdWaitEvents?

Tags: vulkan

In 7.5, the Vulkan spec says about [`vkCmdWaitEvents`](https://renderdoc.org/vkspec_chunked/chap7.html#vkCmdWaitEvents)

> The first synchronization scope only includes event signal operations that operate on members of `pEvents`, and the operations that happened-before the event signal operations. Event signal operations performed by `vkCmdSetEvent` that occur earlier in submission order are included in the first synchronization scope, if the logically latest pipeline stage in their `stageMask` parameter is logically earlier than or equal to the logically latest pipeline stage in `srcStageMask`.

I'm confused by this phrasing. Does this mean the first synchronization scope is the signalling of events that are passed in to `pEvents`, **plus** any events that are submitted earlier and meet the stage mask and submission order requirement, or is it event signals are **both** passed in and meet the requirement?

In either case, since you can just pass in events with `pEvents`, what is `srcStageMask` is useful for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first synchronization scope only includes event signal operations that operate on members of `pEvents`, and the operations that happened-before the event signal operations.

The first scope of `vkCmdWaitEvents` is only the hypothetical signal on the `pEvent` (and all the stuff that *happens-before* it transitively, as would be defined by whatever signaled the event).

> Event signal operations performed by `vkCmdSetEvent` that occur earlier in submission order are included in the first synchronization scope, [...]

`vkCmdSetEvent` cannot be reordered past `vkCmdWaitEvents` by the driver. It would basically be a broken if it did. I.e. if you call:

```
vkCmdSetEvent(e);
vkCmdWaitEvents(e);
```

then the driver is **not** allowed to execute it as:

```
vkCmdWaitEvents(e);
vkCmdSetEvent(e);
```

> if the logically latest pipeline stage in their `stageMask` parameter is logically earlier than or equal to the logically latest pipeline stage in `srcStageMask`.

The reordering prohibition only applies if certain rules are followed.

If you record:

```
vkCmdSetEvent(e, stageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT);
vkCmdWaitEvents(e, srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT);
```

then you would read that as: "signal event after all `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`s, and then wait on all events that signal before `TOP_OF_PIPE`." But that is an empty set! Nothing can be after `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` and before `TOP_OF_PIPE` at the same time! So the wait might not register such a signal.

> In either case, since you can just pass in events with `pEvents`, what is `srcStageMask` is useful for?

Imagine a signal being nothing other than a bit being flipped somewhere in the memory. Then you might as well be asking why there are pipeline stages in Vulkan pipeline barriers at all. Worst case scenario, some driver might need where in pipeline stuff originates and where stuff is consumed.

Usually I think that `stageMask == srcStageMask`, but as a matter of design, Vulkan driver is not forced to remember your own stuff for you. It will simply ask you again.